# Can firebase_ml_vision package recognise cyrillic?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using the firebase_ml_vision package to create an app that recognises cyrillic text. It has come to my attention that the package works only for latin characters or am I mistaken.

Are there any alternatives that work with Flutter and can recognise the cyrillic alphabet? For example how to connect to the cloud version of the Firebase ML kit?

Answer (score 0):

Support List 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/langid-support

Yes. support Cyrillic

You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision 
reference document https://medium.com/flutterpub/ml-kit-and-text-recognition-in-flutter-4b3035b5ad2c

Comment: This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-text) says that on device only latin characters are recognised so how do you detect text in cyrillic except from the cloud. But then how do you connect it to the cloud?